# Python > Selenium: Web-scraping in a "logged-in" environment based on links from a text file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-signin

*Compatible for **ChromeDriver***

This program seeks to accomplish the following:

> 1. Automatically sign-in to a website;
> 2. Visit a link / link(s) from a text file;
> 3. To scrape data from each page visited this way; and
> 4. Output all scraped data by print().

*Kindly skip to **Part 2** for the problem area, as part 1 is tested to work for step 1 already. :)*

The code:

**Part 1**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.website1.com/home")

main_page = driver.current_window_handle 
time.sleep(5) 

##cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept"]').click() 
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="google-login"]/span').click() 
for handle in driver.window_handles: 
    if handle != main_page: 
        login_page = handle 

driver.switch_to.window(login_page) 

with open('logindetails.txt', 'r') as file:
   for details in file:
        email, password = details.split(':')

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]').send_keys(email) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next"]').click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(password) 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next"]').click() 
driver.switch_to.window(main_page) 
time.sleep(5)
```

**Part 2**

> In *alllinks.txt*, we have the following websites:
>
> •  website1.com/otherpage/page1 
>   
> •  website1.com/otherpage/page2
>   
> •  website1.com/otherpage/page3

```
with open('alllinks.txt', 'r') as directory:
    for items in directory:
    driver.get(items)
    time.sleep(2)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-xl')
    for element in elements:
            print ([element])
    time.sleep(5)


driver.quit()
```

**The outcome:**

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 53.463 seconds
```

*... and zero output*

**The problem:**

> Location of the element has been verified, am suspecting that the *windows* have something to do with why the driver is not scraping.

All inputs are welcome and greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I've missed out on including the "iframe", which is quite important for elements not directly selectable via window.

> ```
> iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='LegacyFeature__Iframe-tasygr-1> bFBhBT']")
> driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
> ```

After switching to the target *iframe*, we then run the code to find and print the elements we're looking for.

```
time.sleep(1)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-xl')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Once logged-in, you can pretty much direct the webdriver to other pages on the site, even based on a text file that has all the links of interest:

> Suppose that the text file (*shown below as "LINKS.txt"*) had the
>   following links: 
>   
>  • https://www.website.com/home/item1 
>   
>  • https://www.website.com/home/item2 
>   
>  • https://www.website.com/home/item3

```
with open('LINKS.txt', 'r') as directory:
   for items in directory:
    driver.get(items)
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='LegacyFeature__Iframe-tasygr-1 bFBhBT']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(10)
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-xl')
    for element in elements:
        print(element.text)

time.sleep(10)
```

The code above should allow you to visit pages *...item1*, *...item2*, and *...item3* (as per the ".txt" file), scrape the elements, and print output.

Comment: use WebDriverWait()

Answer (score 1):

URL's used in `driver.get()` must include the protocol (i.e. `https://`).

`driver.get('website1.com/otherpage/page1')` will just raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks Corey, never quite thought about that in the question too... cheers mate!